# Unable to modify global variable in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to update the value of a variable which is globally declared, from a python function. And I am feeding this function to a Pool.map() method. But  I don't see variable getting updated. Please explain what is happening and what is the fix?

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
a=0
def fun(num):
    global a
    if num==4:
        a=4

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool=Pool()
    pool.map(fun,[1,2,3,4,5,6])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(a)
```

Output=0
Expected output = 4

Comment: Check out the section on [sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: they are *different processes* so they don't share state.

Comment: `from multiprocessing import Pool, Value

a = Value('i', 0)


def fun(num):

    if num == 4:
        a.value = 4


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(fun, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(a.value)
` I'm sorry with the formatting. Hope this helps.